# How to make Azure storage part of the publish process?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and ASP.NET MVC4 on a web project of mine. I'm publishing to Azure. This is very cool because I can configure it to use a local database, and test API keys for various third party APIs that I use, when I am developing locally. Then, when I publish I have it configured to use my live database as well as my live API tokens, etc. All of this is done through the app config file.

But, I also have a few resources that I am storing in Azure Storage blobs. I have some larger downloads, images and things that I link to in my website. Right now, this is a completely separate process, where I use a third party tool to manually upload these files after I publish. In my MVC views, I have URLs to them hardcoded, instead of using `@Url.Content`.

This seems like something that I bet VS can automate for me as well, but I do not know how. Does anybody know if VS can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no out-of-the-box way to "publish" Azure blob as part of your publish process.

You can, probably do it yourself by developing a [custom MSBuild Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx). Never tried this before, but sounds like it should work.